# Expose kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I've applied the yaml for the [kubernetes dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard).

Now I want to expose this service with the public IP of my server: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/#objectives

But there is no service/deployment on my cluster:

```
$ sudo kubectl get services kubernetes
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   63d
$ sudo kubectl get deployment
NAME               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The command that you ran is fetching objects in **default** namespace.

However, Dashboard is deployed on **kube-system** namespace.

```
kubectl -n kube-system get services kubernetes
kubectl -n kube-system get deployment
```

I am giving you this info according to the link that you share [kubernetes dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard) . And namely the [YAML file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml)

Answer (score 0):

Oky thanks, now I get the right name:

```
sudo kubectl -n kube-system get deployment
NAME                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
calico-kube-controllers   1/1     1            1           63d
coredns                   2/2     2            2           63d
kubernetes-dashboard      1/1     1            1           103m
tiller-deploy             0/1     1            0           63d
```

But I still can't expose the service

```
sudo kubectl expose deployment kubernetes-dashboard
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "kubernetes-dashboard" not found
```

As mentionned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/#objectives)

Comment: kubectl expose deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system

Comment: do kubectl get all --all-namespaces to see check in what exact namespaces your objects are

Comment: as mentioned by @VKR, you need to specify namespace. Please  also note that imperative commands are not the optimal way how to handle Kubernetes. It's much easier to create YAML files with Kubernetes manifests, track them in VCS and apply  them with kubectl apply :)

Comment: ```sudo kubectl expose deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
Error from server (AlreadyExists): services "kubernetes-dashboard" already exists```
But there is not exposed port: ```ubuntu@kubernetesmaster:~$ sudo kubectl get service
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   63d```
Sorry, I really dont know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

SO, to reproduce and show how does it works - I spawned new fresh cluster on [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/).

Lets see what we have after applying dashboard yaml:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
secret/kubernetes-dashboard-certs created
serviceaccount/kubernetes-dashboard created
role.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
rolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/kubernetes-dashboard-minimal created
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard created
service/kubernetes-dashboard created


kubectl get deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
NAME                   DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   1         1         1            1           3m22s


kubectl get services kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP   10.0.6.26    <none>        443/TCP   5m1

kubectl describe service kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system
Name:              kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:         kube-system
Labels:            k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"},"name":"kubernetes-dashboard"...
Selector:          k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.0.6.26
Port:              <unset>  443/TCP
TargetPort:        8443/TCP
Endpoints:         10.40.1.5:8443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

During this [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/):
1) `kubernetes-dashboard` deployment has been created. Note that it was created with the `k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard` [label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/).
2) `kubernetes-dashboard` [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) was created and works using `k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard` [selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/.

So basically when you receive such an error - this is expected. Because `kubectl expose deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system` is trying to create new service with the  `kubernetes-dashboard` name.
Just to play with it - you can easily expose the same, but use another service names, for example:

```
kubectl expose deployment kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system --name kube-dashboard-service2
service/kube-dashboard-service2 exposed
```

Note that default `kubernetes-dashboard` service is created using [`ClusterIP`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) type - so you are able right now to access it
1) withing the cluster
2) using kubectl proxy from local machine

```
$ kubectl proxy
In browser: http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

If you want to expose the same - you can use:
1) [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

2) [Nodeport service type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)
 In 2 words: edit `clusterIP --> Nodeport` type  while `kubectl -n kube-system edit service kubernetes-dashboard` and access dashboard  using https://[node_ip]:[port]

More detailed article is here: [How To Access Kubernetes Dashboard Externally](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-access-kubernetes-dashboard-externally/)

3) [Loadbalancer service type](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer). This is Cloud specific feature, so it will work only with cloud providers

> Traffic from the external load balancer is directed at the backend
>   Pods. The cloud provider decides how it is load balanced.
>
> Some cloud providers allow you to specify the loadBalancerIP. In those
>   cases, the load-balancer is created with the user-specified
>   loadBalancerIP. If the loadBalancerIP field is not specified, the
>   loadBalancer is set up with an ephemeral IP address. If you specify a
>   loadBalancerIP but your cloud provider does not support the feature,
>   the loadbalancerIP field that you set is ignored.