# I have installed kuberntess dashboard on cloud server but i can not access the dashboard while checking it shows running

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed the Kubernetes dashboard on the cloud server but I can not access the dashboard publicly.

While checking namespace, it shows `running`.

How I can fix such an issue or can anybody share me how to expose the Kubernetes dashboard publicly?

while accessing publicly it throws an error message can anybody help me on this case?
"forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expose kubernetes dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726663/expose-kubernetes-dashboard)

Comment: @Federico klez Culloca I have worked according to suggested comments but I can not access the dashboard publically while accessing it through an error "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"""

Comment: @dan hi, I only edited the question to make it more readable. I don't know the answer to your problem, sorry.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/5087/kubernetes-unable-to-login-to-dashboard)

Comment: @OhHiMark i have tried it but nothing is changed

Comment: if this helps finially i have been able to slove the problem through nginx